Is homotopy equivalence of continuous functions compatible with function composition?
Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces, and let $f, f' : X \to Y$ be continuous functions. We say that $f$ and $f'$ are homotopically equivalent, and we write $f \simeq f'$, if there exists a continuous function $H: X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that for all $x \in X$, we have $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = f'(x)$.
Now, let $Z$ be another topological space and let $f_0, f_1 : X \to Y$, $g_0, g_1: Y \to Z$ be continuous functions such that $f_0 \simeq f_1$ and $g_0 \simeq g_1$. Do we necessarily have $g_0 \circ f_0 \simeq g_1 \circ f_1 $?
I think i found a proof of this, but there's a step i think is a little fuzzy (the continuity of $H_3$). The proof is as follows: Since we have $f_0 \simeq f_1$, there exists a continuous function $H_1 : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ such that for all $x \in X$, $H_1 (x, 0) = f_0 (x)$ and $H_1 (x, 1) = f_1 (x)$. Also, since we have $g_0 \simeq g_1$, there exists a continuous function $H_2 : Y \times [0,1] \to Z$ such that for all $y \in Y$, $H_2 (y,0) = g_0 (y)$ and $H_2 (y, 1) = g_1 (y)$. Now let $H_3 : X \times [0,1] \to Z$ be the function given by
$$H_3 (x, t) = H_2 (H_1 (x, t), t)$$
for all $x \in X$, $t \in [0,1]$. Notice that for any $x \in X$ we have
$$H_3 (x, 0) = H_2 (H_1(x, 0), 0)= H_2 (f(x), 0) = g(f(x))$$
and
$$H_3 (x, 1) = H_2 (H_1 (x, 1), 1) = H_2 (f'(x), 1) = g'(f'(x)).$$
Now, is it correct to say that $H_3$ is continuous because it is the composition of two continuous functions? Namely, $H_3 = H_2 \circ \varphi$, where $\varphi: X \times [0,1] \to Y \times [0,1]$ is the function given by $\varphi (x, t) = (H(x, t), t)$ $\forall x \in X, t \in [0,1]$, which is continuous because both its components are. I don't find this proof very convincing and feel like i went offroad somewhere. For example, by my reasoning, the function $H_4 : X \times [0,1] \to Z$ given by $H_4 (x, t) = H_2 (H_1 (x, t), t^2)$ for all $x \in X$, $t \in [0,1]$ would also work, which i find very weird.

That looks good, I think.

Please format your question into paragraphs. As it is right now it is hard to read.

The key is that if $u:A\to B$ and $v:A\to C$ are continuous, then $w(a,b)=(u(a),v(b))$ is a continuous function $A\to B\times C.$ In your case, $(x,t)\mapsto (H_1(x,t),t)$ is thus a continuous function $X\times [0,1]\to Y\times [0,1].$

There's nothing at all wrong with your proof. It's true: the composition of two continuous functions is continuous. And it's true: A function with values in a product of two spaces is continuous if and only if its two component functions are continuous.
And it's also true, for similar reasons, that $H_4$ is continuous, and that $H_4$ is therefore another homotopy between the two functions in question. There's no reason you can't have multiple different homotopies between the same two functions; you can no doubt manipulate the homotopy variable to get many more different homotopies.
Another point to make here is that manipulation of the homotopy variable is an important trick in algebraic topology and homotopy theory; this trick comes up a lot. Perhaps you've seen this trick in other contexts. Just as an example, consider the proof that for any continuous functions $f,g,h : X \to Y$, if $f \simeq g$ and $g \simeq h$ then $f \simeq h$. One knows by hypothesis that there exists a homotopy $H_1 : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ between $f$ and $g$ and another homotopy $H_2 : X \times [0,1] \to Y$ between $g$ and $h$. By manipulating the homotopy variable one obtains a homotopy $H_3$ between $f$ and $h$:
$$H_3(x,t) = \begin{cases}
H_1(x,2t) &\text{if $0 \le t \le 1/2$} \\
H_2(x,2t-1) &\text{if $1/2 \le t \le 1$}
\end{cases}
$$
